# PDF sorting--move, delete, and rotate pages only

Tags: windows, gratis, pdf, document-management

I'm looking for easy-to-use desktop software that shows thumbnails of the pages in a PDF document, and the pages can be sorted using click-and-drag, right-click rotate, or right-click delete.  The less features the better.

It needs to be free (non-commercial use) without bundle software or freemium nags, or inexpensive (under $30 per seat for 50+ licenses).  Windows 10 supported required, Mac OS 10.12 would be nice.

Comment: Note that all of that functionality is available through the built-in OSX Preview application - albeit with some keyboard shortcuts for the rotate. Not sure how critical it is to have the same workflow on both platforms.

Comment: @PeterM That's very cool.  I didn't need to use keyboard shortcuts.  Sometimes Macs are easier...

Comment: Preview has a lot of power.  I prefer it to the Adobe Viewer on Windows when I need to annotate PDFs as well.

Answer (score 2):

**[PDFSam Basic](https://pdfsam.org/pdfsam-basic/)** is [open source](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfsam/) and focus to do these exactly basic functionalities. It can split, merge, extract pages, mix and rotate PDF files.

It runs not only on Windows, but Mac, Linux, and even has a command-line (cli) version.

The download is available here: https://pdfsam.org/download-pdfsam-basic/

Comment: PDFSam Basic doesn't have thumbnails, apparently you have to pay for PDFSam Visual, which is bit over budget.

Answer (score 1):

[Xodo](https://www.xodo.com) is completely free, and available on Windows desktop and mobile from the Store.

It includes the ability to move, delete and rotate pages using the mouse.
http://feedback.xodo.com/knowledgebase/articles/723594-deleting-rotating-and-exporting-pages-within-a-d

Comment: Interesting find.  Not a requirement of the question, but is there any way to download Xodo and use it locally on a Win7 desktop?

Comment: It is only available from the Windows Store, which might not be available o Win7. There is also a chrome app/extension version, that allows similar actions.
http://feedback.xodo.com/knowledgebase/articles/664153-organizing-pages

Comment: A UWP app isn't going to work for us, it needs to be an actual desktop application.